# Windows Forms Application Like Outlook Design Advice

Tags: c#, winforms

I will be developing an application more or less like an GUI similar to outlook

My question is when you open a outlook it seems to be a one form only. So they handle it.

Are they user controls drag and dropped on only one form or something else.

Secondly

[image]

And how can i create a menu- this panel for my application and how it will work on XP?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you will be developing an Application, what have you tried thus far..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE In the past i had developed less than 10 application. On all application i simply create normal forms but this time i am wandering how the application like outlook- single form is created and i am asking for advice/links etc and not code to know what they are single form etc...

Answer (score 0):

As for exactly how Microsoft lays out Outlook, I'm not even going to guess.  But for the controls that you are showing in your example, these would be done in a "Ribbon Control".  You should take a look at these examples 
[Example of ribbon control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23199/WPF-C-Ribbon-Control-Library) and here is
[Another example of ribbon control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/364272/Easily-Add-a-Ribbon-into-a-WinForms-Application-Cs)

Check them out.  I think you'll find that it a good starting point.